# jQuery: How to display and hide elements alternately with a sliding motion?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one button and if the button is clicked, a text should `.slideDown()`. If the button is clicked again, the text should `.slideUp()`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="button">CLICK ME!</div>
<div id="text" style="display:none;">
    Example Text
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#text').slideDown();
    $('#button').addClass('button-clicked');
});
$('#button.button-clicked').on('click', function() {
    $('#text').slideUp();
    $('#button').removeClass('button-clicked');
});
```

Is there a more simple solution?

Comment: I think you'd better not change an element ID. you can add or remove classes to tag a specific state!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for all that - just use [`slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#text").slideToggle();
   $(this).text(function(i, text){
       return text === "Up" ? "Down" : "Up";
   });
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eU28E/2/)

Comment: Yes, but then the button doesnt change... Edit: I want, that the button changes to a down or an up-button.

Comment: @user3389375 What do you mean it doesn't change?

Comment: @null: He was using the id change to change the button color from red to green -- see the question.

Comment: @user3389375 Is this more like it?

Comment: @user3389375 I'm confused as to how the other answer actually answers your question, judging by the question and your comments?

Comment: @null: If you look at the question, he says (regarding the CSS), "I just switched the colors for the same button from red to green when the text is shown". Presumably that means he depends on the id change to update the appearance of the button, and you aren't changing the id.

Comment: @RussellZahniser I noticed that, however the title, the question itself and his comment on my answer indicated he wanted an "up and down" button display - as in the actual text changed. He even commented "Yes, that's nice" after I edited that in?

Comment: @null Edited the question so it is more easy to understand. Thanks, you had the best answer. I am sorry if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

just use slideToggle()

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#text").slideToggle(); //will handle slides  automatically
});
```

Comment: "Yes, but then the button doesnt change...  I want, that the button changes to a down or an up-button."

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do `.click()`, you are attaching a new event handler. So by the time the button has been clicked twice, there are two event handlers that fire every time you click it, one sliding down and one sliding up.

If you need the id of the button to change each time you click it, do something like this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#text").slideToggle();
  $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") == "button" ? "button-clicked" : "button");
});
```

The click handler stays attached to that button element even though the ID is changing.

If the id change is just triggering a different appearance through CSS, a more conventional approach would be to do `$(this).toggleClass("clicked")`, and then define the clicked state in `#button.clicked`.